# MySQL script able to parse read and write json data to a table DB

Tags: mysql, json, algorithm, scripting

I want to parse some not-so-simple json data and read into a model then write that modelled data into a DB. Or rather write into a DB without involving the model itself?

My json looks like this.

```
{
    "parent": [{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "name a",
        "children": [{
            "id": "34",
            "name": "cvfd",
            "children": []
        }, {
            "id": "5643",
            "name": "name tyu",
            "children": [{
                "id": "5433",
                "name": "blah",
                "children": []
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

And my table would have simple two columns such as "id" and "name".

Just read/write might be straightforward but it involves parsing as well.

Any suggestion/advice appreciated and even another alternative to Mysql itself for better approach?

Comment: I would recommend you have an additional column on the table. call it a parent_id... every child record you insert you should store its parents id that way you know what the hierarchy is for future use

Comment: John Ruddell, good point. Thanks, and any other suggestions?

Comment: what language are you doing this in?